# Java reflection for private static method with parameters

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a problem using the `invoke` method in java.

I have a method to use to provide me a `Method` object and it looks like:

```
 public static Method provideMethod(String methodName, Class targetClass) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,null);

    //Set accessible provide a way to access private methods too
    method.setAccessible(true);

    return method;
}
```

Ok this method works perfectly when I'm trying to access methods, from any context (static, or non static), that have no arguments.

Now the problem is that I can't call invoke and pass arguments to a method that have arguments, for instance:

I have the following method :

```
private static boolean createDirectory(String path, String fileName) {
  ... 
}
```

And I want to invoke it like this:

```
 Boolean created = (Boolean) DataUtils.provideMethod("createDirectory", FileUtils.class).
            invoke(null, String.class, String.class);
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createDirectory []`.

**Does somebody knows how can I invoke a private static method that have parameters ?**

**And, how can I pass values to that methods arguments?**

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're explicitly calling a reflection method which looks for a method declared with the given parameter types - but you're not providing any parameter types.

If you want to find *any* method with the given name, use `getDeclaredMethods()` and just filter by name... but then when you call `invoke`, you need to provide the string *values*, not the parameter types.

Alternatively, change your `provideMethod` call to *also* accept the parameter types, so you can use:

```
DataUtils.provideMethod("createDirectory", FileUtils.class,
                        String.class, String.class)
         .invoke(null, "foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're specifically only looking up methods with no arguments when you call

```
Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,null)
```

In order to find the createDirectory method, you'd need to call

```
targetClass.getDeclaredMethod("createDirectory", String.class, String.class)
```

but at present your `provideMethod` method has no way of doing this.

I would suggest that you change the signature of `provideMethod` so that it allows the caller to pass in the classes of the arguments that they're looking for, like so:

```
public static Method provideMethod(String methodName, Class targetClass, Class... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);

    //Set accessible provide a way to access private methods too
    method.setAccessible(true);

    return method;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
```

to something like that

```
Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes);
```

and your `provideMethod` accordingly.